# Debian Failed at step EXEC spawning - Systems Service - Permission Denied

Tags: debian, systemd, systemd-service

I'm following this tutorial exactly line by line:
https://docs.meilisearch.com/learn/cookbooks/running_production.html#step-4-run-meilisearch-as-a-service

It has a step to setup the Meilisearch as a service using this config:

```
cat << EOF > /etc/systemd/system/meilisearch.service

[Unit]
Description=Meilisearch
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/lib/meilisearch
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/meilisearch --config-file-path /etc/meilisearch.toml
User=meilisearch
Group=meilisearch

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
EOF
```

However when I run it as suggested I get this error:

```
systemd[1]: Started Meilisearch.
systemd[2834]: meilisearch.service: Failed to execute command: Permission denied
systemd[2834]: meilisearch.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /usr/local/bin/meilise
systemd[1]: meilisearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
systemd[1]: meilisearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

However when I run the command specified in the service config it works perfectly:

```
 /usr/local/bin/meilisearch --config-file-path /etc/meilisearch.toml
```

This is on Debian 10 and Debian 11.

Comment: I had to run `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/meilisearch` to make it work